# Getting Facebook's New Payer Promotions to Work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment, facebook-credits

Has anyone been able to get the [New Payer Promotions described in Facebook's recent developer blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/13/drive-payer-conversion-with-new-api/) to work? According to [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/payer_promotion/) you should be able to query a new field, `is_eligible_promo` via the Graph API.

Formatting a call like this only results in the "id" field being returned for me though.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=is_eligible_promo?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to sign up for or enable this somewhere? Or does it just not work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing with a friend's account it appears that the documentation is incorrect.

If the user **is eligible** it will do what it describes and return the `is_eligible_promo` field with a "1" as the value.

If the user **is not eligible** the `is_eligible_promo` field will not be returned at all.

The documentation says "This query returns the following data in its response: The value 1 indicating the user is eligible or 0 indicating the user is not eligible." Apparently this is not correct.

My account was not eligible therefore it did not return a value for this field.

Comment: This is my understanding of how this works - when you use the FQL method (`select is_elegible_promo from standard_user_info where...` ) then you'll get 0 or 1, in Graph API fields are omitted if there's no value for them